# how to instert populated documents without: casting it in ObjectId then populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to avoid this (see comments below):

```
var UserSchema = Schema({
  name: String
});

var UserGroupSchema = Schema({
  users: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' } ]
});

var user = new User({ name: 'John' });

var userGroup = new userGroup();

userGroup.users.push(user); // auto cast user in its objectId ! How to avoid that ?

UserGroup.populate(userGroup, { path: 'users', model: 'User' }); // Get back the user object (this step should be obsolete)
```

I do not want to declare this:

```
var UserGroupSchema = Schema({
  users: [ User ]
});
```

Because i want to be able to find my users without looking into UserGroups.

I really hope there is something to avoid that because i don't see how to write clean code this way.

Answer (score 0):

> Because i want to be able to find my users without looking into UserGroups.

Specifically that means that you can only use references, which means saving new users separately before pushing a reference onto (and saving) a UserGroup instance.

I assume that a user can belong to more than one UserGroup, which means using subdocs (the `users : [ User ]` variant) can't really be used anyway.

Comment: ``UserGroup.find({ 'users.name' : 'John' })`` works, but ``User.find({ 'name' : 'John' })`` wont, that's why i would like to use references.

Even if i save my User, then push it into a UserGroup, it will be casted in ObjectId, however, i do not need to save my UserGroup to populate the Users, so since nothing happens between the "casted push" and the populate, i guess there is a way to avoid that.

Comment: @Ludo any changes to a document (whether it's to create a new user or you pushed a reference to one to a usergroup instance) need to be followed by a save, otherwise the changes won't end up in the database.

Comment: yes i know that, but i am talking about te step before the save, i want to keep my UserGroup in memory, i am working on a video game and i don't want to execute obsolete saves for permormences concerns.
I just want to build my group with my users before, use this document, and execute a save later.

Comment: @Ludo I don't see how you can do that. It's either subdocs (which you don't want) or storing refs (which you also don't want).